# How to make custom domain alias in Go server?

Tags: dns, go, domain-name

i have web app running on top of Go. Let's say this web app running on `domain.com`, every user can create their on page with custom sub domain like `user.domain.com` .

Some of my user want to add their own custom domain, ex: `userdomain.org` or `page.anotherdomain.com`. How do i accomplish this?

I'm already search on google, they should add `CNAME` alias, but it shown a `DNS Resolution Error`

Answer (score 1):

Have the user add their domain to your app, then in your http handler check if `req.Host` matches a known user's page.

```
func handleUserPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    user, err := db.FindUserByDomain(r.Host)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteStatus(404)
        return

    }
    //display user's page based on r.URL.Path maybe?
}
```